# What is this property that implies the existence of a global solution to a Cauchy problem called in English?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

In my ODEs class I have recently learned that if a function $f:I\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval and $n$ is a positive integer) has the property that there is some $r>0$ and some continuous function $a:I\to [0, \infty)$  such that $$|\langle x, f(t, x)\rangle| \le a(t) ||x||^2, \forall t\in I, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n \text { with }||x||>r,$$
then the Cauchy problem $x'=f(t, x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$, where $(t_0, x_0)\in I\times \mathbb{R}^n$, has a global solution, i.e. there is some function $\varphi : I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\varphi'(t)=f(t, \varphi(t))$ for all $t\in I$ and $\varphi(t_0)=x_0$.

I would like to know what the name of this property is in English. I tried translating the name this property was given in my class (it would be something like "bilateral dissipativity"), but I can't find anything named like this. So, either my translation is bad or there is a totally different name for this in English.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that $\langle,\rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $||\cdot||$ denotes the Euclidean norm, i.e. the norm induces by the standard scalar product (I am not really sure whether this was obvious or relevant since any two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, but I figured that it's better to be a bit pedantic than not to specify all the details).

Comment: It's a bound on the radial component of the vector field, so escape or convergence to zero is about exponential in the radius, depending on what $a(t)$ actually is. I do not know a special name for this, neither in German nor in English.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you! Is it common to use this property to tackle the problem of global solutions? I don't really know too many texts on ODEs, but I haven't seen this approach anywhere except for my class.

Comment: Properties of $x^Tf(t,x)$ are frequently used as exercises. Similarly, when discussing trapping regions, only the normal component of a vector field needs to be examined. Perhaps also when modifying a vector field to avoid exploding solutions outside some region-of-interest, this claim can be used as a guiding principle. I do not have a reference or link where this is actually used.